# Getting the value (but not key) from SASS list variable

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I want to have a navigation bar that scales the content to the current breakpoint as defined in global site media queries but I can't seem to target the items in the SASS list correctly.

**HTML**

```
<div class="contain-header">
    <header class="top-bar">
        <!--nav here-->
    </header>
</div>
```

**Global settings (SASS)**

```
$breakpoints: (
  small: 0,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1200px,
  xxlarge: 1440px,
);
```

So when the screen is < 1200px, the navigation content would have a `max-width` of `1024px`.

**SASS (not working)**

```
.contain-header {
    .top-bar {
        margin: 0 auto;
        @each $item in $breakpoints {
            @include breakpoint(#{$item}) {
                max-width: #{$item};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This causes an error on compile:

> WARNING: breakpoint(): "small 0" is not defined in your $breakpoints setting.

(repeated for each item in `$breakpoints()`)

So how do I call `#{item}` so that instead of outputting `medium 640px` it outputs `640px` (or `medium` for that matter)? And how do I change `max-width: #{$item};` to target the value of `$item - 1`?

N.B. I'm using Foundation where the `@include breakpoint(){}` is a mixin that wraps the css inside a media query & `$breakpoints()` is one of the framework's variables (http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/media-queries.html#sass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `@each $key, $value in $breakpoints` and leave out the interpolation:

```
.contain-header {
  .top-bar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    @each $key, $value in $breakpoints {
      @include breakpoint($key) {
        max-width: $value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```